# Need help in categorizing where at least one Female appears in a series of ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of ID with Gender information. I need to categorize ID's where at least one Female appears. Below is the data for reference.

```
ID  Gender
1   Female
1   Female
2   Male
2   Male
3   Female
3   Male
4   Male
4   Male
4   Male
4   Male
4   Female
5   Female
5   Male
5   Female
6   Male
6   Male
6   Male
6   Male
7   Female
8   Male
8   Male
9   Male
10  Male
10  Male
11  Male
11  Female
13  Male
14  Male
```

I was trying to create two columns one if ID'S are the same and another column to check if it has Female. Based on two column results Output will be created. But somehow I think their will be a better way.

```
 import re,os, subprocess,  pandas as pd, numpy as np
    data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Analytics\TA Dashboard\test\test.xlsx")
    data['match1'] =data['Reference ID'].eq(data['Reference ID'].shift())
    data['match2'] =data.eq('Female').any(axis=1)
```

Output needs to be "Yes" Or "No" based on the combination of ID & Gender, for the same ID if Female is there on any ID, it should be "Yes" for all ID else NO.

```
ID  Gender  OUTPUT
1   Female  Yes
1   Female  Yes
2   Male    NO
2   Male    NO
3   Female  Yes
3   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Male    Yes
4   Female  Yes
5   Female  Yes
5   Male    Yes
5   Female  Yes
6   Male    NO
6   Male    NO
6   Male    NO
6   Male    NO
7   Female  YES
8   Male    NO
8   Male    NO
9   Male    NO
10  Male    NO
10  Male    NO
11  Male    Yes
11  Female  Yes
13  Male    NO
14  Male    NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where `Gender` is `Female`, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `transform` with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df['OUTPUT'] = df.Gender.eq('Female').groupby(df.ID).transform('any')
# If you want Yes/No strings
# df['OUTPU'] = df.OUTPUT.map({True:'Yes', False:'NO'})

    ID  Gender  OUTPUT
0    1  Female    True
1    1  Female    True
2    2    Male   False
3    2    Male   False
4    3  Female    True
5    3    Male    True
6    4    Male    True
7    4    Male    True
8    4    Male    True
9    4    Male    True
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i got one additional problem here...what if I have to apply filter on one additinoal column Status then apply the above logic, without dropping the filtered rows from dataset.

Below is the data, here i need to filter where status is not equal to xyz and xy then it should apply above logic. Remember i dont want to drop the filtered rows as well from main datasource.

ID  Gender status
1   Female xyz
1   Female xyz
2   Male   xyz
2   Male   xy
3   Female x
3   Male   y
4   Male   xyz
4   Male   xy
4   Male   xy
4   Male   xy
4   Female xab
5   Female xac
5   Male   xy
5   Female xyz
6   Male   xyz
6   Male   xy
6   Male   xy
6   Male   xy
7   Female xyc
8   Male   xy
8   Male   xyz
9   Male   xy